# R cannot be resolved to a variable - My First App

Tags: android

I created a android app with eclipse but when I try to execute I've this problem.

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

In the instruction where I use "R" like : `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`
builder tell me an error and exactly `"R cannot be resolved to a variable"`

I've read something about this but I haven't found my solution.
It's like R is `android.R` and not my layout folder. I don't know what to do! I need a little hint. This is really my first android App.

Comment: ctrl+shift+O ...then select the R.java of  your project

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error?rq=1

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error?rq=1

Comment: Usually Resource file isn't automatically generated if there are errors in your .xml files so, do a double check in your `res/layout/activity_main.xml` layout :)

Comment: If you click on it, it will give a few default solutions, in your case maybe importing com.example.myfirstapp.R would work.

Answer (score 1):

If you have android.R in the import lines, delete it. Then, to import the appropiate class:

- Ctrl + Shift + o (Windows)
- Cmd + Shift + o (Mac)

If you get a window due to a conflict, choose the R class of your project.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing Project-> Clean? That might fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the res/ directory doesn't have any compilation errors, which will prevent the IDE from producing a valid R.java file, which is used to resolve the R symbol.

Answer (score 0):

best way to resolve this problem,  you should use small  alpha-bate latter and underscore when you give the file name in drawable folder , res folder , or when paste the image in drawable folder always the name of the images only in small latter . Then clean the project .

Answer (score 0):

I literally tried everything but nothing worked until I went to Window/Android SDK Manager and I installed the SDK Build tools. I then cleaned my app, waited few seconds and the errors disappeared.